# Why is $\mathbb Z_{7} \times \mathbb Z_{11}$ isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_{77}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm studying for my introductory abstract algebra class and have found myself confused on direct products of groups in my book It says that  $\mathbb{Z}_{7} \times \mathbb{Z}_{11}$ (Direct Product) is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{11}$

They didn't give a reason in the book I've seen similar examples that mention the GCD of the groups, which doesn't make much sense to me. I figure that one way to explain would be to give a counting argument but that wouldn't really be using any group theory

Comment: Did you mean $\mathbb Z_{77}$?   If so, use the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem).

Comment: @lulu is their another way to go about it? I haven't learned the CRT yet.

Comment: Well, it's  equivalent to the CRT (at least for those particular numbers).

Comment: Show that the map $\,n \mapsto (n,n)\,$ from $\,\Bbb Z\,$ to the product has kernel $77\Bbb Z$ then apply the First Isomorphism Theorem.

Answer (score 1):

They're both cyclic groups of order $77$. That automatically makes them isomorphic.

Comment: Does having equal order imply we have an isomorphism

Comment: @Temirzhan Not in any way (unless the order is prime). But if they're cyclic, then yes, equal order means isomorphic.

Answer (score 1):

(Here, I'm writing $\mathbb{Z}_7 = \{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$ under addition modulo $7$, and likewise for $\mathbb{Z}_{11}$.)

The group $\mathbb{Z}_7\times \mathbb{Z}_{11}$ has order $77$. Consider the element $(1,1)$ in this group. What's the order of this element? (In other words, for which number $n>0$ do we have $n(1,1) = (0,0)$?) By Lagrange's theorem, it must divide $77$, which means it must be $1, 7, 11$ or $77$. Let's try them out:

- $1(1,1) = (1,1) \neq (0,0)$
- $7(1,1) = (0,7) \neq (0,0)$
- $11(1,1) = (4,0) \neq (0,0)$

so we know, by process of elimination, that it must be $77$. And indeed:

- $77(1,1) = (0,0)$

which is what we wanted.

This shows that the group is *cyclic*: it's generated by the element $(1,1)$. But that's what $\mathbb{Z}_{77}$ is: the cyclic group of $77$ elements.